# ¿ Que extensión de PHP debo habilitar?

Tags: php, visual-studio

Hola estoy tratando de personalizar una plantilla de WordPress, y a abrir una copia del proyecto con Visual Studio Code, lo primero que me dice en el recuadro de la parte derecha de abajo, donde avisa las actualizaciones es el siguiente dialogo:
***No se puede validar porque no hay ningún ejecutable PHP establecido. Use el ajuste "php.validate.executablePath" para configurar el ejecutable de PHP.***

Instale Visual Studio hace unos días, con mi nueva instalación de Ubuntu, por lo que esta tal y como se instala.
¿ Que extensión o extensiones debo instalar para trabajar mi plantilla de WordPress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola que tal primero que nada debes de abrir Visual Studio > ir a Archivo > Preferencias > Configuración > se abrira el archivo settings.json > ahí encontraras `"php.validate.executablePath": null,`
En esa parte debes de agregar la ruta del ejecutable de php. (`php.exe`), Ejemplo:

```
{
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/php.exe"
}
```

Espero te haya ayudado u orientado en algo.

Comment: Como dice @demianrc es asi con el alcance de que debe ser tu ruta la cual debes colocar! no la que pone él!

Comment: Hola @MiguelEspeso En Linux siempre se encuentra en /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.

Comment: Gracias a los dos, voy a instalar PHP y le doy por buena la respuesta